# Faces not responding to UV unwrapping

Tags: uv

I am encountering a weird error with my model in that the UV map isn't responding to some specific faces on a UV sphere I have boolean merged to my character. I'm new at blender so this might be an obvious fix. In short some of the faces on this ball aren't matching the UV despite being selected and clearly fitting on the UV image. Images show unselected for clarity and selected to show UV unwrap.

[image: UV wrap fail not selected]

[image: UV wrap fail selected]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: "Responding" and "matching" how? Do you mean the shapes are different?

Comment: To me it looks as if the right side of the sphere does not have the material with the UV grid applied, it's just white. Could it be that those faces have a different material? The fact that they are unwrapped does not mean that they automatically get a material assigned...

Comment: Here is the model: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9EQPLKE9" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9EQPLKE9/)

Comment: Again novice, how would I check that a particular face isn't assigned to a different material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select one of those white faces you'll see that they are assigned to the second material, which is completely empty, just assign them to the first material:

[image]